# Understanding the decision process in politics - How much knowledge does a politician need?

Tags: decision-making

**Edit:** Thank you for your helpful comments. Based on them, I decided to modify my Question.

I am wondering how decisions are made in politics. In particular, what are the skills the politicians involved need to have for the creation of *policies*?

Following the example of the European commission (see [How to review the decision-making of the different functions of the European Union?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41442/how-to-review-the-decision-making-of-the-different-functions-of-the-european-uni)), the basic steps for creating a policy are:

1. The current state of the system, its advantages and disadvantages are assessed.
2. Based on expert reports, the policy is created.
3. The policy is passed on to an external committee.

From this perspective, politicians mainly need to be able to

- efficiently work in a team,
- incorporate knowledge from various fields,
- must be able to understand scientific arguments.

**Questions**: When it comes to creating a policy, what makes a politician different from any other profession where these 3 faculties are required? What are the difficulties a politician is facing when creating an agenda/policy?

I am happy to hear any comments on that. Any suggestions (books, articles, documentaries) on how I could deepen my understanding of the decision processes in politics, especially on how policies are created, are very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  This question is far too broad to be answerable in a few paragraphs, because of the wide variety of decisions that a politician has to make, and the wide variety of contexts (wider policy, implementation details, emergencies, among others).  If you can [edit] your question to narrow it down, then it may help with creating an answer.

Comment: This may be too cynical, but the decision process often seems to be "make a decision" then "look for reasons to support that decision".  Douglas Adams had something similar in one of his Dirk Gently books: Instead of software that takes data and uses logic to output a decision, there is software that takes data and a decision and outputs the logic to deduce the latter from the former.  In the book it had been sold exclusivly to the US gov. (although the Department of Defense was still using the beta pre-release...)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to narrow my question down. I hope now, given a concrete context, my question is more clear.

Comment: @Hulk: I dunno... I think a general answer is possible, without getting bogged down in specificities or lost in abstractions.

Comment: Yes, it's basically the opposite of the process described most of the time.

Comment: I'm still missing basic, essential parts of the process in the question. In particular, the split between the civil service and the politicians, and the path to power for politicians (whether that's elections or violence). There _are_ rare democratic processes where a group comes together for a purpose and achieves something, but we typically refer to those as NGO's (non-governmental organizations) to make it explicit they're not politicians.

Comment: @MSalters: I think you're missing the forest for the trees. As I see this question, the OP is asking what particular *role* the politician fills in society (shades of Arendt's *vita activa*). It's a question I personally find interesting in the abstract, philosophical sense, without all the messy pragmatics of implementation.

Comment: I'm confused about process here. This question has sat with three reopen votes for a couple of days now with no action. Does it need more votes to be considered?

Comment: @TedWrigley Yes, two more. It's only on Stack Overflow that questions need three votes to be reopened.

Comment: @F1Krazy: Got it.